# Matplotlib more efficient way to update chart when using slider to scroll through chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider

I want to be able to scroll through a lengthy chart.  Is there a more efficient/faster way than having to clear the axis and replot the whole thing every time the scroll bar moves?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import random
x=[c for c in range(300)]
y=[random.randint(1,10) for c in range(300)]

showbars=100

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(x[:showbars],y[:showbars])

def slidebar(pos):
    pos = int(pos)
    ax.clear()
    ax.bar(x[pos:pos+showbars],y[pos:pos+showbars])

slidebarpos = plt.axes([0.1, 0.01, 0.5, 0.03], facecolor="skyblue")
slider = Slider(slidebarpos, '', 0, len(x)-showbars, valinit=0)
slider.on_changed(slidebar)
slidebar(0)

plt.show()
```

This is slow on my computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you could plot the bars only once, and use the slider just to change the range that is shown, i.e. the limits of the x-axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(300)
y=np.random.randint(1,10, size=300)

showbars=100

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(x,y)

def slidebar(pos):
    ax.set_xlim(pos-1, pos+showbars+1)

slidebarpos = plt.axes([0.1, 0.01, 0.5, 0.03], facecolor="skyblue")
slider = Slider(slidebarpos, '', 0, len(x)-showbars, valinit=0)
slider.on_changed(slidebar)
slidebar(0)

plt.show()
```

One could also keep the same bar's in place, but change their height and fake the ticks and labels in such a way that the bars look like being updated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoLocator
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(300)
y=np.random.randint(1,10, size=300)

showbars=100

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

bars = ax.bar(x[:showbars],y[:showbars])

loc = AutoLocator()

def slidebar(pos):
    pos = int(pos)
    for bar, yi in zip(bars, y[pos:showbars+pos]):
        bar.set_height(yi)
    ticks = loc.tick_values(pos, showbars+pos)
    ax.set_xticks(ticks-pos)
    ax.set_xticklabels(ticks)

slidebarpos = plt.axes([0.1, 0.01, 0.5, 0.03], facecolor="skyblue")
slider = Slider(slidebarpos, '', 0, len(x)-showbars, valinit=0)
slider.on_changed(slidebar)
slidebar(0)

plt.show()
```